# Wrong username/password. Access denied.phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

I cannot get into phpmyadmin, ive configured the config.inc.php file so i can login but still the authentication fails, i even tried true and false for passord

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'test';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';
```

Comment: I think mysql by default doesn't allow you to log in as root. Did you go through the conf script?

Comment: You Can't Login Into Your PhpMyAdmin Or Can't Get A Php File To Connect To It?

Comment: root user by default has no password for as far as I know

Comment: I have told auth_type to pop up the box then i login or should do using http auth_type

Comment: if im using localhost:8000 is there anything else that would need editing in config.inc.php in phpmyadmin>?